# Spring MVC. Не возвращаются данные из метода в контроллер

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

Доброго времени суток. Второй день бьюсь над проблемой. Не могу получить данные из метода в список в контроллере.
Методы контроллера:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/searchForm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showSearchForm(@RequestParam(value = "idProvider", required = true) Integer idProvider, Model model)
        throws DaoException {
    Supply supply = new Supply();
    supply.setProvider(providerDao.findById(idProvider));
    model.addAttribute("idAttribute", supply);
    return "formOfSearch";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String search(@RequestParam(value = "idProvider", required = true) Integer idProvider,
        @RequestParam(value = "department", required = false) String department,
        @RequestParam(value = "carNumber", required = false) String carNumber,
        @RequestParam(value = "arrivalDate", required = false) @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE) LocalDate startDate,
        @RequestParam(value = "arrivalDate", required = false) @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE) LocalDate endDate,
        @ModelAttribute("idAttribute") Supply supply, Map<String, Object> map) throws DaoException {

    List<Supply> supplyList = supplyDao.searchByCriteria(idProvider, department, carNumber, startDate, endDate);
    map.put("search", supplyList);

    return "searchList";
}
```

Метод searchByCriteria в который должны передаваться данные из контроллера и который должен вернуть список данных из базы:

```
    @Override
public List<Supply> searchByCriteria(Integer idProvider, String department, String carNumber, LocalDate startDate,
        LocalDate endDate) throws DaoException {
    try {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = manager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Supply> query = cb.createQuery(Supply.class);
        Root<Supply> root = query.from(Supply.class);
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
        if (idProvider != null) {
            predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("provider"), idProvider));
        }
        if (department != null) {
            predicates.add(cb.like(root.get("department"), department));
        }
        if (carNumber != null) {
            predicates.add(cb.like(root.get("carNumber"), carNumber));
        }
        if (startDate != null) {
            predicates.add(cb.between(root.<LocalDate> get("arrivalDate"), startDate, endDate));
        }
        // Predicate[] predicatesarr = predicates.toArray(new
        // Predicate[predicates.size()]);
        // query.select(root).where(predicatesarr);
        query.select(root).where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[] {}));
        List<Supply> list = manager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
        return list;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new DaoException("An error has occurred in class SupplyDaoImpl, method searchByCriteria.", e);
    }
}
```

JSP страница формы поиска formOfSearch:

```
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"    prefix="form"%>
   <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
   <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8"%>

    <h1>Поиск поставок</h1>
    <c:url var="searchUrl"
        value="/supplyController/search?idProvider=${idAttribute.provider.idProvider }" />
    <form:form class="form-horizontal" modelAttribute="idAttribute"
        method="POST" action="${searchUrl}">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="provider.idProvider"></form:label></td>
                <td ><form:input
                        path="provider.idProvider" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="carNumber">Номер автомобиля:</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="carNumber" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="department">Отдел:</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="department" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="arrivalDate">Дата прихода от:</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input type="date" path="arrivalDate" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="arrivalDate">Дата прихода до:</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input type="date" path="arrivalDate" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <input value="Найти" input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </form:form>
```

JSP страница вывода результатов searchList:

```
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<h1>Список поставок</h1>
<table class="table">
    <thead style="background: #9AC0CD">
        <th>Дата поставки</th>
        <th>Номер автомобиля</th>
        <th>Фамилия водителя</th>
        <th>Телефон</th>
        <th>Отдел</th>
        <th>Товар</th>
        <th>Документ поставщика</th>
        <th>Документ получателя</th>
        <th>Кладовщик</th>
        <th>Диспетчер</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <c:forEach items="${supplyList}" var="searchList">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${searchList.arrivalDate }" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${searchList.carNumber }" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${searchList.driverName }" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${searchList.phone }" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${searchList.department }" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${searchList.product }" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${searchList.vendorDocument}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${searchList.documentReceiving}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${searchList.storekeeper}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${searchList.dispatcher}" /></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Метод поиска работает правильно (находит данные в БД и возвращает список с нужными данными), но в контроллере я получаю пустой список. 
Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему или хотя бы направьте в какую сторону копать.

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос, Вы не получаете данные в контроллере вызвав `supplyDao.searchByCriteria...`, или они там получаются, но не выводятся на jsp страницу?

Comment: Не получаю данные в контроллере вызвав метод. List<Supply> supplyList = supplyDao.searchByCriteria(.....). supplyList пустой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вопросе неправильно передаются данные на jsp страницу. У Вас данные получаемые из БД кладутся в обычную `Map`, и далее нигде не используются. Эти данные нужно добавлять с помощью `Model.addAttribute...`, метод должен выглядеть так:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String search(@RequestParam(value = "idProvider", required = true) Integer idProvider,
        @RequestParam(value = "department", required = false) String department,
        @RequestParam(value = "carNumber", required = false) String carNumber,
        @RequestParam(value = "arrivalDate", required = false) @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE) LocalDate startDate,
        @RequestParam(value = "arrivalDate", required = false) @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE) LocalDate endDate,
        @ModelAttribute("idAttribute") Supply supply
        //, Map<String, Object> map удалить
        , Model model //добавил
        ) throws DaoException {

    List<Supply> supplyList = supplyDao.searchByCriteria(idProvider, department, carNumber, startDate, endDate);
    //Добавляем в атрибут с названием "supplyList", как на jsp, а не "search"
    model.addAttribute("supplyList", supplyList);

    return "searchList";
}
```

Comment: Заработало. Спасибо большое.